# How to turn off Amplify datastore datasync to cloud when using Amplify api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a few doubt that is unclear in was amplify docs.

1. Can I turn off data sync to DynamoDB, when using amplify graphQL API with datastore?
2. Can I query data from dynamo DB using amplify datastore?
3. If I can query data using a data store, what is the use of API, they should merge all the things?

Answer (score 0):

The datastore sync options are slightly different depending on the language you are using.  I think explaining the differences might help you understand things better:

**DynamoDB** = your database

**Appsync API** = graphql api that connects to DynamoDB via resolvers initially built out by amplify using your graphql.schema file.  If you add amplify codegen  it will build out the client code for you as well, based on your schema file.

**Datastore** = Basically it is a really nice caching layer. It can sync in data via Appsync from Dynamo down to your client in the datastore cache.  you can then run queries on datastore in offline mode because the data can be local.  The sync helps datastore stay up to date with the live data from the DB.  So when querying with datastore, you are usually just querying locally. If you data is up to date it saves the trip to the DB.  If you were to use the Appsync API codegen client, it is calling the db through your resolvers each time.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: You said ```It can sync in data via Appsync from Dynamo down to your client```, I have doubts  1. if my DynamoDB has 10 billion items will it sync down to the client's mobile local storage? 2. What about Amplify.Datasote.delete? If I have shown data to the user if I want to remove that from local storage will Amplify.Datasote.delete delete the data in the cloud? I just want to use local storage without sync but I need API , is there way to stop it from synching?

Comment: 1) yes, but not all of your data. The client for datastore has options to set limits, and select a subset of data to sync. 2) yes it will delete from the cloud once online. 3) I do not think you can use it without sync.  If you do not want to sync anything down, you may be able to accomplish that by using the Datastore's syncexpression methos